# Enter a number into a message box then replace numbers in a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro. When I run the macro I would like a message box to appear asking for file number. That file number would replace the 000 in the macro and the macro would run.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("C4:D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "000"

Sheets("Sale ()").Select
Sheets("Sale ()").Name = "Sale (000)"

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Sheets("Sale (000)").Copy Before:=Workbooks("SALES INDEX.xls").Sheets(2)

Windows("SALES INDEX.xls").Activate
Sheets("Index").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Insert
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "000"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Sale (000)'!C9"
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
Range("B4:F4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sale (000)'!R9C3"
Range("B3:F3").Select
Range("C3").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sale (000)'!R3C36"
Range("B3:F3").Select
Range("D3").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sale (000)'!R3C44"
Range("B3:F3").Select
Range("E3").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sale (000)'!R5C36"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Sale (000)").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this at the top:

```
Dim st As String
st = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter file number", Type:=2)
```

and then replace **carefully** the 000

for example:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = st
```

Even though **st** is a string, you can enter values like 000 and have all the characters preserved.

**EDIT#1**

another example

replace:

```
"='Sale (000)'!R9C3"
```

with

```
"='Sale (" & st & ")'!R9C3"
```

Comment: This worked for the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = st but did not replace the Sheets("Sale ()").Name = "Sale (st)" with the number. I am having trouble changing the sheet tab name to the input number of the box.

Comment: I have changed the st to FN. On the inputbox I would like to have a Default:= Workbooks("SALES INDEX.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value + 1